# How to make git forget about a file which was behind a symbolic link but is now deleted

Tags: git

I am trying to stash the changes but it is giving below error:

```
error: 'log/.keep' is beyond a symbolic link
fatal: unable to process path log/.keep 
Cannot save the current worktree state
```

'log' is a symbolic link to a folder outside the git repository and 'log/.keep' file has been deleted some time ago, I removed it from tracking files list using command `git rm --cached log/.keep` and it is not showing in the tracking file list now but still when I am trying to do `git stash` it is giving the above error, I have read through multiple stackoverflow solutions to similar issues but nothing is working out, I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: That's ... odd and interesting, and might be a `git stash` bug. If you can make a small reproducer for it (see [mcve]), that might pinpoint the source of the problem and hence determine whether it's some operator error or a true git-stash bug. If it *is* a bug, your particular release version of Git will matter since `git stash` got a bunch of work done on it over the years.